# Avoid "bump" image on fixed position with height:vh

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a background image that fits the `height` of the screen, with `width` larger than the screen and `height:100vh`.

When I start scrolling the page on a mobile browser (tested on Chrome and Firefox mobile), there is a small bump on the page. I guess is due to the value of the `height` being in `vh` value. How can I avoid that?

Here is the CSS

```
.cover{

    background-image: url(img.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height:100vh;
    z-index:-1
}
.cover{position:fixed; width:100%; z-index:-1; top:0; left:0}
```

Comment: can you show us a snippet / fiddle?

Comment: It only happens on mobile browser (I edited now the question)

Comment: probably due the browser address-bar / header animation?

Comment: I notice than when I start scrolling the image enlarges

Comment: @JoseBorges Hi, I am currently facing this issue as well. Did you manage to get it solve?